# Troubles with XPath Plugin Python

Tags: python, selenium

So i am getting the path id('page-content')/x:div[6]/x:div/x:div/x:div/x:a[1]/x:img

How would i go about clicking the img?

I've tried

lol=find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='emoji-items nano-content']//a[@title=':heart:']/img")

as well as

lol=find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title=':heart:']/img")
which i believe should work, but it instead gives me an error

Comment: //a[contains(@title, 'heart')]   Please add more details if this is not working, like the html section, the error stack trace.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/84f3e00131b9ee51dc998b761599a0af The highlighted section is the line i am trying to click. Can you please explain how you come up with this as well

Comment: when i use the line lol=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@title, ':heart:')]") i'm getting an error it is unable to locate it

Comment: if you are using contains then you don't have to use the :'s. Maybe the page is not loaded and you need some wait. Try the selector manually in the firebug. My opinion is that the page is not loaded or you have this element in an iframe, in which case you need to switch to the iframe first. Please check manually and debug.

Comment: Yup, got it. The page wasn't loaded so my script was doing it too fast. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did is: select all links elements (a) that contains heart in the title.

I tried to avoid using @title= because sometimes you might have issues due syntax used in the methods for finding the element or in other methods due to special characters like :.

The resulted path was:

```
//a[contains(@title, 'heart')]
```

If more elements are found you need to add another element in front of this to restrict the section that is searched in.